# Creating Setup/Installation Project in visual studio

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2017

I have created an standard installation project in vs2017. I require to update the string connection over user input and run an script to Create DB on selected String connection.

I am following the following article https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/446121/Adding-connection-string-during-installation#_articleTop

But I do not understand where to create the Installation class.

Any suggestion on how to perform this task?

Comment: how about downloading the sample and actually having a `look` - or am i missing something?

Comment: Better to use INNO installer

Comment: @JohnB I see no sample to download,do you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people fighting Against this, I found a more detail tutorial.
https://codeteddy.com/2016/04/04/creating-an-msi-package-for-c-windows-application-using-a-visual-studio-setup-project/.

The instalattion class, must be added into the proyect you want to install.

Regards,

Comment: Hi, so glad to hear that and please mark your reply as answer, then will help others easier search this useful information, thanks in advance.